# Certificate pinning and SSL

Tags: android, security, https, mobile-application, certificate-pinning

I am trying to learn about making secure mobile applications. I am curious to know, do we need Certificate pinning if our network calls from mobile to server use https ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should save it as a raw file in the folder of your app and use it to call the server for the requests.
Pay attention, if you have a self signed certificate you should force it as made by trusted authority.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you are saying is pinning only. My question was why is it required if https already provides the security.

Answer (score 0):

> I am curious to know, do we need Certificate pinning if our network calls from mobile to server use https ?

https guarantees that the data in transit between your mobile app and API server is encrypted and cannot be spied on by third parties, thus partially preventing it against Man in the Middle attacks.

So I say partially because an attacker can induce users to install a custom ssl certificate in order for them to use a free wifi. This is usually done with fake wifi captive portals where you have to sign in in order to have free wifi, like the ones you found in airports, trains, etc. If an attacker succeeds in tricking the user then all the traffic is routed through the attackers computer and despite being https it can be decrypted once the mobile app is using the attackers custom certificate, but the attacker will always use the original certificate when communicating with the API server, thus neither the API, server, mobile app or the user are aware that the communication is being intercepted and maybe even tampered with.

So using certificate pinning will prevent any type of a Man in Middle Attack to occur, even the ones where the user of the mobile app is the attacker that intentionally decrypts is own traffic in order to reverse engineer the mobile app communication with the API server in order to gain enough knowledge to mount an attack against it.

Now is time for the bad news... Certificate pinning can be bypassed when the attacker as access or controls the mobile device. [This article](https://blog.approov.io/the-problem-with-pinning) walks you through on how certificate pinning can be used and bypassed by using a framework like [xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/), that will intercept the calls to validate the certificate, thus bypassing the validation process.

So should I use certificate pinning? Yes you should, because is one more layer of defence and requires more effort for an attacker to reverse engineer your mobile app, that he may deem not be worthy the effort, but if he deems worthy the effort then you may want to search in google for a Mobile App Attestation solution to protect further the communication between the mobile app and the API server.

But keep in mind that while certificate pinning may be easy to implement in your mobile app it may be an operational nightmare to maintain. Be sure to read the section *PINNING IS A NIGHTMARE* in the link I referenced previously about bypassing certificate pinning.

## Edit

You can read the article [Steal that API Key with a Man in the Middle Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack) to see a practical example on how a secret can be extracted from a https request sent from a mobile app to the backend API, by performing a MitM attack.

> So, in this article you will learn how to setup and run a MitM attack to intercept https traffic in a mobile device under your control, so that you can steal the API key. Finally, you will see at a high level how MitM attacks can be mitigated.
>
> While we can use advanced techniques, like JNI/NDK, to hide the API key in the mobile app code, it will not impede someone from performing a MitM attack in order to steal the API key. In fact a MitM attack is easy to the point that it can even be achieved by non developers.

Afterwards you can also take a look to the article [Securing HTTPS with Certificate Pinning on Android](https://blog.approov.io/securing-https-with-certificate-pinning-on-android) to understand how you can implement certificate pinning to prevent a MitM attack.

> In this article you have learned that certificate pinning is the act of associating a domain name with their expected X.509 certificate, and that this is necessary to protect trust based assumptions in the certificate chain. Mistakenly issued or compromised certificates are a threat, and it is also necessary to protect the mobile app against their use in hostile environments like public wifis, or against DNS Hijacking attacks.
>
> You also learned that certificate pinning should be used anytime you deal with Personal Identifiable Information or any other sensitive data, otherwise the communication channel between the mobile app and the API server can be inspected, modified or redirected by an attacker.
>
> Finally you learned how to prevent MitM attacks with the implementation of certificate pinning in an Android app that makes use of a network security config file for modern Android devices, and later by using TrustKit package which supports certificate pinning for both modern and old devices.

I hope that both articles have made more clear why certificate pinning is recommended to be used to secure https connections from prying eyes.

### EDIT 2

If you want to implement certificate pinning but are afraid of making any mistake while creating the `network_security_config.xml` configuration file then just use this free [Mobile Certificate Pinning Generator](https://approov.io/tools/static-pinning/) to create it for you:

[image: Mobile Certificate Pinning Generator - Config Tab]

and it will give you a `network_security_config.xml` configuration file ready to be copy pasted:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It clears a lot of things. If I don't use certificate pinning and only encrypt the data that I send to my server, do you think that would be sufficient? Hacker can attack it and see my traffic but data would be encrypted and only my server will have the private key to decrypt the data.

Comment: Well if the attacker controls the device where the mobile app is installed or it can trick the user to install some introspection framework like Frida or Xposed(they exist disguised inside of what looks like a normal app) then he can grab the data before is encrypted.